# Athena how to filter array struct?

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I got this sample data and would like to filter product_name like '%shirt%'. How can I filter this?

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: can you show what the data looks like (not just the formatted table, is it JSON)? And what programming language do you need it in?

Comment: it is in JSON data in S3 bucket. I want to use AWS Athena to query it

Comment: You probably need `CROSS JOIN UNNEST` to extract individual product from the array (you may need to cast your input JSON to `ARRAY<JSON>` first) and then `json_extract` to get `product_name` field from product JSON.

Comment: Can it be done in Athena?